# Doing a query loop with a condition

Tags: sql, database, delphi

I have now changed my focus to doing a query loop with a condition if true.
I know my code is a mess and I am not even sure if I am doing it right.
What happens is I can get the first record but not the additional ones that meet the condition under the loop.

Here is what I have so far:

```
procedure TAddressListForm.LoadMCListbox();
Var
GetID : Integer;
Begin
GetID := strtoint(ContactUnit.ContactForm.IDLabel.caption);
ALMCListBox.Items.Clear;
ContactForm.RootsDB.Connected := True;
AddListQuery.close;
AddListQuery.SQL.Clear;
AddListQuery.sql.text := 'SELECT * FROM AddAddress WHERE [ContactID] = :CID';
AddListQuery.ParamByName('CID').Value := GetID;
AddListQuery.open;
AddListQuery.first;
while not AddListQuery.eof and AddListQuery.ParamByName('CID').Value = GetID do

begin                 ALMCListbox.items.add(inttostr(AddListQuery.FieldByName('AddID').AsInteger) + ';'
+ inttostr(AddListQuery.fieldbyname('ContactID').asinteger) + ';' + AddListQuery.FieldByName('AddStreet').AsString
+ ' ' + AddListQuery.FieldByName('AddCity').AsString);
next;
AddListQuery.Close;
End;
```

End;

Sorry if this is really basic, I am trying hard to understand this.

Thank you

Comment: What about writing *AddListQuery.Next* instead of just *next*?

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't close the query within the loop.

Comment: Third, `and` has higher precedence than `=`, so you need parentheses: `... and (a = b)`.

Comment: And fourth: You probably shouldn't have your `CID` test in the `while` loop condition. Instead, put it in your SQL as a `where`. *Update:* You already have it there, so just remove the `CID` test in `while`.

Comment: Anyhow: You should buy and read a good book about programming in general and Delphi in particular. Also, you must read the documentation for the libraries you are using (here: FireDAC?). And, finally: learn to use the debugger and to break up problems in small parts, so you can try each part individually.

Comment: Oh wow, Thank you folks very much. Does the order of what I have look right? and where should I close the query?

Comment: Close it after the `while` has `end`'ed.

Comment: Andreas ReJbrand, you are correct. I have a book on firedac it's helpful I just don't understand my errors all the time. Today is the first time I am using a query.

Comment: I really can't say enough of how much I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop terminates if the expression evaluates to false. So the first record that doesn't meet the ID condition terminates it. Try something like this:

```
while not AddListQuery.eof do
begin                 
  if AddListQuery.ParamByName('CID').Value = GetID then
  begin
    ALMCListbox.items.add(inttostr(AddListQuery.FieldByName('AddID').AsInteger) + ';'
      + inttostr(AddListQuery.fieldbyname('ContactID').asinteger) + ';' + AddListQuery.FieldByName('AddStreet').AsString
      + ' ' + AddListQuery.FieldByName('AddCity').AsString);
  end;
  AddListQuery.next;  
End;
AddListQuery.Close;
```

And remember that while loop checks a condition before the execution of its content, plus use parenthesis in your boolean check expressions to avoid unwanted outcome, fe:

```
while (not AddListQuery.eof) and (AddListQuery.ParamByName('CID').Value = GetID) do
```

Comment: don't forget BeginUpdate / EndUpdate..